# Add Record With API with use of form in symfony 2

Tags: php, api, symfony

This is my basic action for add record through api

```
    public function createAction(Request $request){
      $data = array();
      $data['employeeCode'] = $request->request->get('employeeCode');
      $data['employeeDescription'] = $request->request->get('employeeDescription');
      $data['firstName'] = $request->request->get('firstName');
      $data['lastName'] = $request->request->get('lastName');
      $data['address'] = $request->request->get('address');
      $data['suburb'] = $request->request->get('suburb');
      $data['postcode'] = $request->request->get('postcode');
      $data['country'] = $request->request->get('country');
      $data['phone'] = $request->request->get('phone');
      $data['mobile'] = $request->request->get('mobile');

      $emp = new Employees();
      $emp->setEmployeeCode($data['employeeCode']);
      $emp->setEmployeeDescription($data['employeeDescription']);
      $emp->setFirstName($data['firstName'] );
      $emp->setLastName($data['lastName']);
      $emp->setAddress($data['address']);
      $emp->setSuburb($data['suburb']);
      $emp->setCountry($data['country']);
      $emp->setSuburb($data['phone']);
      $emp->setCountry($data['mobile']);

      $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
      $em->persist($emp);
      $em->flush();
      $view = View::create();
      $view->setData($emp);

      return $view;
```

this works for me but i want to bind it with my employee form so i can get  every validation from my form validator and i am new to symfony2 so i dont know that how to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really easy:

```
$emp = new Employees();

$form = $this->createForm(new EmployeesType(), $emp);
$form->bindRequest($request);

if ($form->isValid()) {
    $emp = $form->getData();
    (...)
}
(...)
```

Comment: hey thanks for help..
i have tried this ways but it didnt get success because all data are come from request parameter so if i do this it give me error like all field are required

Comment: i got sql errors which are not suitable to end user for example i set employeeCode(Not Null)  in sql then i got sql error that emploeeCode required when i already set employee code in my post request parameter data['employeeCode']

Comment: it's because of names of your form fields."bind" method (instead of "bindRequest") should work fine for you (i didn't check it but seems fine). Let me know if this helps

Comment: i have done as you say and use bind instead of bindRequest and now i got this error..
:"Expected argument of type \"numeric\", \"string\" given","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Form\\Exception\\UnexpectedTypeException

       $form = $this->createForm(new EmployeesType(), $emp);
       $request = $this->getRequest();
       $form->bind($request);
This way i done

Comment: sorry, i forgot to say, that you should pass an array to "bind" rather than $request object

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate your entity on an api, just use the validate method: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

You don't have to use a form !!!

Here an example:

```
public function createAction(Request $request){

    // ...previous code...

    // We valide manually the employee without a form !
    $validator = $this->get('validator');
    $errors = $validator->validate($emp);

    // If there are errors....
    if (count($errors) > 0) {

        return new Response('Errors !');
    }

    // Otherwise we save it !

    $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
    $em->persist($emp);
    $em->flush();
    $view = View::create();
    $view->setData($emp);

    return $view;
}
```

Of course it will call all the validators defined on your employee entity.

Also you can just call a group of validtors:

```
$errors = $validator->validate($emp, array('api_creation'));
```

Also, here a good tutorial to build an API with symfony2: http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/